# Convert a SQL query to EntityFramework

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

How can I convert this query to Entity Framework Query?

```sql
select Price,
(
    select Cost.Title 
    from Cost 
    where Cost.CostID= CostItem.CostID
) as nameCost
from CostItem 
where ItemID= 11
```

Comment: Please never just post SQL and ask for conversion. At least show a class model so navigation properties and the multiplicity of associations are visible. Also, show your own first efforts. They clarify more to us than you might think.

Comment: ok, thanks for your reminding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var result = dbContext.CostItems
    .Where(item => item.ItemId == 11)
    .Select(item => new { Price = item.Price, nameCose = item.Cost.Title })
```

Just make sure you have you relations in entity objects properly set up

Answer (score 1):

Your query can also be written with a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT
    ci.Price,
    NameCost = c.Title
FROM CostItem ci
LEFT JOIN Cost c
    ON c.CostID = ci.CostID
WHERE ci.ItemID = 11
```

Converting this to Linq using C#, you get:

```cs
var t =
    from ci in CostItem
    join c in Cost on ci.CostID equals c.CostID into lc
    from c in lc.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where ci.ItemID == 11
    select new {
        Price = ci.Price,
        NameCost = c.Title
    };
```